# iOS NSURLSession Download

Tags: ios, nsurl

I got this code to implement something which helps me downloading a file from a given URL.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSLog(@"Temporary File :%@\n", location);
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *docsDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out1.zip"]];
    if ([fileManager moveItemAtURL:location
                             toURL:docsDirURL
                             error: &err])
    {
        NSLog(@"File is saved to =%@",docsDir);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to move: %@",[err userInfo]);
    }

}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    //You can get progress here
    NSLog(@"Received: %lld bytes (Downloaded: %lld bytes)  Expected: %lld bytes.\n",
          bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}
```

Second part:

```
-(void) downloadFileWithProgress
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hayageek/downloads/SimpleBackgroundFetch.zip"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask =[ defaultSession downloadTaskWithURL:url];
    [downloadTask resume];

}
```

All of this code is in my Download.m

My download.h is:

```
@interface Download : NSObject
-(void) downloadFileWithProgress
@end
```

I really dont know how to get the download starting. In another class I created a button which should start the download:

```
-(IBAction)buttonStartDownload:(id)sender {
[Download downloadFileWithProgress];
}
```

The *error* is in the last line:

```
No known class method for selector 'downloadFileWithProgress'
```

But why?

Comment: We need more information, did you import your download helper class? Why do you need three different classes?

Comment: Ok, yes i imported the "Download.h" in the "DownloadViewController.m" Isn´t it useful to outsource the download code into a single class and refer to it in a downloadViewController class?

Comment: I think it is easier for now to just have everything in your DownloadViewController class, since you would just outsource a single function.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try this and will let you know whether i had success or not ;)

Answer (score 1):

The method '-(void) downloadFileWithProgress' is an instance method so you cant call this method by using class name 'Download'.

In order to call this method you need to create an instance of 'Download' class and call the method on that instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Method -(void)downloadFilwWithProgress in instance method...So to call that method

-(IBAction)buttonStartDownload:(id)sender {
Download *downldObj=[[Download alloc]init];
[downldObj downloadFileWithProgress];
}


If you write method +(void)downloadFilwWithProgress then you can call like this.[Download downloadFileWithProgress]
```